# Django settings.py can't import my local module

Tags: python, django, python-import

My Django tree looks like this

```
git/src
├── myproject
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── mysharedlib.py
│   └── urls.py
└── www
    ├── myotherlib.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

It works except that in `settings.py` I have

```
import mysharedlib
```

But this raises an exception

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysharedlib'
```

Importing `myotherlib` from `views.py` raises a similar error.

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

Django starts the application where your manage.py is located.
Try :

```
from myproject import mysharedlib
```

Or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Django starts the application where your manage.py is located. Try :

from . import mysharedlib